# WebView is not opening google.com

Tags: android, webview

My webview is able to load both https & http sites
But not https://www.google.com

It doesn't throw any error either.

Here is my code.I am unable to solve this problem

```
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button1);
        final EditText et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText1);
        final WebView wv1=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.WebView1);

        wv1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv1.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        wv1.setInitialScale(100);

        et.setFocusable(true);


        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 wv1.loadUrl(et.getText().toString());  
            }
        });

        wv1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return true;
            }
ca
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Page Finished",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        wv1.loadUrl("https://www.bing.com");
```

Thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: Please log the value of url in both overriden methods in your webclient

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=CUfdVPKMMseS8Qfq34CIBQ

Comment: I tried enabling cookies But nothing works so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug in your code

**Your code**

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return true;
        }
```

**Correct code**

```
 public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return false;
            }
```

`ShouldOverrideUrlLoading` should `return false` to *open url in webview*.
`True` is for *opening in some other app*.﻿