# What is gfe_rd=cr&ei= and why this url fails in Android webView?

Tags: android, networking, webview

When I load https://www.google.com in my webview I get `https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei` in 
`onPageFinished` of `WebViewClient` .

When I searched on the internet I couldn't find much info.

The end result is google fails to load in the webview

This question is related with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28484286/3853188)

Any suggestions ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meaning for google homepage parameters (gfe\_rd,gws\_rd,ei)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24300885/meaning-for-google-homepage-parameters-gfe-rd-gws-rd-ei)

Comment: I have updated the question more clearly and it will make much sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What is gfe_rd=cr&ei=?

This is a **cookie link** redirected to your browser based on the country from which it is accessed.

i.e

If we enter https://www.google.com

then it will return like https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=dsjk5k45

- **GFE**: **G**oogle **F**ront **E**nd
- **RD**:  **R**e**d**irect
- **CR**:  **C**ount**r**y
- **EI**:  **E**ngine **I**d

The Engine Id is the cookie that is sent to our browser

[Source](http://duraiamuthan.blogspot.in/2015/02/what-is-gferdcr.html)

---

### Why https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=jkfkl87 fails ?

In the link you had given I found a bug in the code.

`ShouldOverrideUrlLoading` should `return false` to *open url in webview*.
`True` is for *opening in some other app*.

Comment: I have updated my question.Plz consider looking into the link that I have given in the question.